# Encryption key on same database?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, centos

I'm encrypting some sensitive data before passing it to the db. As of now, each user has it's own enc/decr key stored in the db (and the key itself is encr with a master pwd.

I was wondering if it adds any security to store each user's key in a different db, on the same server. Makes sense?

In addition, I'm saving the "master" key on a separate file included only at the moment of encryption, I was thinking of "locking" it down with fewer permissions as possible (CentOS server). What level of permission should I grant to the file?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no added security to storing data in different DBs unless you have different mysql users accessing the different databases.

If you want to store passwords in a db and need to be able to decrypt them for use, you will need a master key that should be stored in a secure location on your server (not the db) that few people have access to.

Also, you should make sure to have the means to change that key in the future (eg, a script that can convert existing encrypted data to use the new key).

Comment: My idea was to create a new user with an unique password, then each time I need the key to decode the data I would create a new connection, get the desired key and close the connection. Does it make sense, or is it just a waste of resources?

Comment: If you're talking about a PDO/Mysqli connection, that's already how it works if you're operating in a web context... that is, unless you have persistent connections turned on.  That wont necessarily give you any extra security though...

Answer (score 0):

If your key is anywhere in the db you might as well not have it. It's like locking your car - and leaving the key hanging by a string from the door handle.

The proper way to store passwords is to HASH (not encrypt!) the password and then store the hash. You then hash login attempts and compared to the stored hash. There is no way to re-create the original password.

Comment: You cannot hash the encryption key, since that would make it irretrievable for use.

Comment: You don't hash the key. There IS NO KEY. You just hash the passwords

Comment: I'm not trying to encrypt the password, passwords are processed with MD5 and do not need to be decrypted (in my case), while the data I'm trying to protect needs to be decrypted, and the only way I imagine to do so is a 2 way encryption method, that somehow needs to rely on  some sort of key, which I don't want to leave only to the end user since if he loses it all data is lost.